# Drag a newly created subview from a collectionView using pan gestures

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, pan

I have a ViewController with a basic collection view below. I am now able to click a cell in the collection view and add a subview of the image selected. 
I am stuck on allowing the user to push down on the cell and drag the new subview onto the mainview without the user having to lift their finger and reselect thus activating the pan gesture.

How do I programmatically initiate the pan gesture for the newly created subview, so it seems like the user is dragging a copy off the collectionView?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    stickerImage = imageArray[indexPath.item]!

    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // update UI on the main thread
            var newImageView = UIImageView(image: self.stickerImage)

            newImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            newImageView.multipleTouchEnabled = true
            newImageView.exclusiveTouch = true
            newImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

            let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handlePan:"))
            panGesture.delegate = self
            newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)


            newImageView.frame = self.view.bounds
            newImageView.frame.size.width = 150
            newImageView.frame.size.height = 150

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(self.reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

            newImageView.center.y = self.view.frame.height - collectionView.frame.height / 2
            newImageView.center.x = cell.center.x

            self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(newImageView)
        }
    }

}

func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(recognizer.view!)
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(recognizer.view)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(view.transform, translation.x, translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: recognizer.view)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding touch methods as touchbegin and touchend. Override these methods and you will not have to care about the pan gesture just need to check the view on which touch is recognised.